# Phantomjs calling functions with variable

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to put this code into a variable and then call that variable from phatom and phantom should generate graph eg: I save this code in `var test="code"` then I call test in phantomjs and it should generate the graph, is it possible?

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
```

Or this can also help
Create js file and call this from a variable

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -scale 2.5 -width 300 -constr Chart -callback callback.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question what exactly you are trying to accomplish. If you have

```
var test = { xAxis: { ... } };
```

and you are trying to access that variable from within a webpage (i.e. to generate the graph in the actual DOM) you have to pass the variable as an argument to the page open method, i.e.:

```
var test = { xAxis: { ... } };
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(function (someVar) {
  ...
  // now you have access to the test variable via someVar
  ...
}, test);
```

If that is not what you are trying to accomplish, please clarify your question and I will do my best to help.